# How to compress a video file using ffmpeg in android?

Tags: android

I am using FFmpeg library to compress video. The user can browse for any video and compress it. Is it possible to use FFmpeg and android ffmpeg client library free or not.

Comment: I don't think there are any native implementations of ffmpeg on android. You can try two things. You can install busybox which comes with ffmpeg and upload it to your device. Or you can 

https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg

build that source to get native ffmpeg for android

Comment: android ffmpeg client library free or not ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Busybox is free. The source linked above is free. You can build it

Comment: hi srinivas i have download github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg source code but how to implement in android

Comment: The instructions to build the source are in the readme.txt. I have not experimented with this before. But the instructions seem fairly straightforward

Comment: Hi, @Kailash I have also worked on FFmpeg, Can you get it any proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer : NO.

Long answer :

It depends on your definition of ***free***. FFmpeg is by itself a free and open source software. However, there are some codecs that are encumbered by patents, like H.264 etc. and as such can be enforced in countries like the US (that have laws granting software patents). However, there are free formats like Theora, Vorbis, VP9 etc. I have *heard* it is possible to build FFmpeg without the encumbered codecs. Such, a library will be **FREE** (as in free beer and freedom) to use in your applications.

EDIT :

Your first goal should probably be to build FFmpeg from source with the codecs for patent encumbered formats excluded. Then, you'd have to *find* or *create* libraries that enable FFmpeg integration with your Android app. Beware of the license these softwares are released under, especially if your application is intended to be proprietary/closed. Do a good amount of research before you begin development. Good luck!

Comment: please give me simple example with source code.thanks

Comment: My knowledge of FFmpeg's integration with Android is nil. The links provided by Srinivas are probably a good place to start. Also, see my edit to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you - it is a Android java library for FFmpeg binary: http://hiteshsondhi88.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/